# Evaluate the Finite Sum with Binomial Coefficient

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation

Evaluate the following sum:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{k}{n}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$$

This almost looks like the Binomial Theorem, except there's that pesky little $\frac{k}{n}$ term in there that changes things up a bit.  I'm not quite sure what steps to take from here.  How do you evaluate this sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $\frac kn\binom nk=\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ to get
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$$
which can be summed by the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{k}{n}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n!k}{k!(n-k)!n}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}=\dfrac{x}{1-x}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}=\dfrac{x}{1-x}\cdot(1-x+x)^{n-1}=\dfrac{x}{1-x}$$

Comment: it's a polynomial.

Comment: Yes and it directly yields to correct answer